# Android Open Document Tree with Activity Result Contract

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, registerforactivityresult

I was recently updating deprecated methods in my App and there is one that I have a few questions about. Did not find any example or explanation describing my use case...
There is a local backup and a restore functions. User has to choose a directory either where to save data to or to restore data from. It was implemented like this:

```
binding.backupBtn.setOnClikListener{
   openDirectory(LOCAL_BACKUP_CODE)
}
binding.restoreBtn.setOnClickListener{
   openDirectory(LOCAL_RESTORE_CODE)
}

private fun openDirectory(requestCode: Int){
   val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
   startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
}
```

And then depending on the request code backup or restore:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode = Activity.RESULT_OK) {
           val uriTree = data?.data ?: return
           if (requestCode == LOCAL_BACKUP_CODE) {
               localBackup(uriTree)
           }
           if (requestCode == LOCAL_RESTORE_CODE) {
               localRestore(uriTree)
    }
  }
}
```

Now with this Activity Result Contracts how can I specify, and is it possible at all, custom request code. Android documentation for accessing a directory still uses *startActivityForResult()*

[Link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory)

*ActivityResultContract.StartActivityForResult()* - is a generic contract that takes any Intent but there is no way to provide custom request code.

As for now I simply created 2 launchers for backup and restore:

```
        val backupRequest = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree()){
            if (it != null){
                localBackup(it)
            }
        }

        val restoreRequest = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree()){
            if (it != null){
                localRestore(it)
            }
        }

        binding.backupBtn.setOnClickListener {
            backupRequest.launch(null)
        }

        binding.restoreBtn.setOnClickListener {
            restoreRequest.launch(null)
        }
```

Is it the way to do it? I looked into custom Contracts, but can't figure out how I can return Uri AND custom variable (request code in this case).

Comment: Yes you use two. That's the whole idea.